# How to reduce the number of matrix multiplications

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix, optimization

Let `A` be a given square matrix whose size is `nxn`. Let `A[i]` denote the `nxn` matrix formed by replacing the `i`-th column of `A` with the zero column vector.

Now I want to calculate the following `(n^4+n^3+n^2)` matrix products:

`{A[x]*A[y]*A[z]*A[w] | for all x=1,...n , y=1,...,n , z=1,...n, and w=1,...,n}`

`{A[y]*A[z]*A[w] | for all y=1,...,n , z=1,...n, and w=1,...,n}`

`{A[z]*A[w] | for all z=1,...n, and w=1,...,n}`

If I calculate each product naively, it would take `O((n^4+n^3+n^2)*n^3)` time complexity (assuming that a matrix multiplication requires `O(n^3)` time).

However, I noticed that there are many duplicate multiplications that can be memoized. Is there an efficient way (like DP) that can reduce the number of matrix multiplications as fewer as possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The first - obvious - optimization is to use results from the 3rd set to calculate the first one.

The second one which comes in mind is slightly more tricky.

Let `B[i]` denote the `nxn` 0-matrix with `i`-th column replaced by `i`-th column of `A` (i.o.w. `B[i] = A - A[i]`).

Then rewrite the matrix product using matrix distribution law[1], like this.
`A[x]*A[y] = (A - B[x])(A - B[y]) = (A - B[x])A - (A - B[x])B[y] = AA - B[x]A - AB[y] - B[x]B[y]`.

Since `B[i]` are sparse matrices with only a single non-zero column, the products above are very easy to calculate, plus the one "full" matrix multiplication - `AA` - need to be calculated only once.

The 3-multiplications case would look like following.
`A[x]*A[y]*A[z] = AAA - B[x]AA - AB[y]A + B[x]B[y]A - AAB[z] + B[x]AB[z] + AB[y]B[z] + B[x]B[y]B[z]`.

After previous step we already have most of the factors (every `B[i]A` and `AB[i]`), if memory is of no concern; or we can easily calculate it (since, once again, the `B[i]` are sparse).

The 4-multiplcations case can then be done analogues.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_the_matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29

Answer (score 0):

Multiply A[z] and A[w], skipping over the '0' column in w in each iteration, and then simply filling that column with zeros in the answer (or if you calloc'd the memory, then its already 0 by default). This is your problem #3

Now, take this matrix, which has a column that is zero (wth column), and multiply A[y] by it, again taking advantage of the fact that the same column is zero and you can skip multiplies. You now have #2.

Repeat this once more multiplying A[x] by this result, taking advantage of the same 0 column.

This means overall, you have 3 * (n-1)*n * (2n) = 6 * n^3 - 6 * n^2 multiplications total (if my math is correct).